# Ranger will not preview images or text

Tags: linux-mint, ranger

I have tried `sudo apt-get purge ranger` and then reinstalling it, but I have not been able to find anything that works. My python version is `2.7`.

Comment: @GAD3R I just added it

Comment: Check the error during the installation of the package `sudo apt install ranger`.

Comment: No errors, but it just suggest I update python-chardet, and now it is working. Sorry for the run around, I am still new to linux. Thanks for your help @GAD3R

Comment: You are welcome , I am asking for the python version because `ranger` depend on `python2.7` and buggy under `python3.5`.

Comment: @GAD3R my bad, it seems that it is only previewing images, but not text any of my cpp files. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `sudo apt --install-suggests install ranger` .

Comment: @GAD3R I couldn't get that to run, but I tried `sudo apt recommends ranger` and it said no missing recommended packages were found

Answer (score 0):

First install a terminal that can render images. Right now [the most advanced terminal is probably **"Kitty"**](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty).

```
apt install kitty
```

Then you'll need to install a new version of ranger. Make sure you've got rid of all the old stuff first.

```
sudo apt get --purge remove "ranger*"
```

Then add a new `ranger`.

```
pip3 install --user ranger
```

Now you simply need to enable previews. Edit `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf`, and add the following

```
set preview_images true
set preview_image_method kitty
```